# cut off points for p-value in wilcox_test

Tags: r, p-value

I'm using `wilcox_test` to perform stats on a grouped bar plot.
https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/rstatix/reference/wilcox_test.html

What are the cutoff points for determining the asterisks in `p.adj.signif` ?

Tried checking here (https://github.com/kassambara/rstatix/blob/master/R/wilcox_test.R), but couldn't really spot the code that does this.

A similar function `compare_means` have symbols meaning the following

```
ns: p > 0.05

*: p <= 0.05

**: p <= 0.01

***: p <= 0.001

****: p <= 0.0001
```

Does the same apply to wilcox_test ? Could you please provide the source ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: `?rstatix:::add_significance`

There's probably a more efficient way to find out, but this worked for me:

- inspect the wrapper function `wilcox_test`:

```
library(rstatix)
wilcox_test
```

The output

```
function (data, formula, comparisons = NULL, ref.group = NULL, 
          ## ...
          test.func <- pairwise_two_sample_test
          ## ...
}
```

shows that at some point work is delegated to an underlying function `pairwise_two_sample_test`. What's this function?:

```
?pairwise_two_sample_test

No documentation for 'pairwise_two_sample_test' in specified packages and libraries:
you could try '??pairwise_two_sample_test'
```

Oops. No documentation found.

- Enter the [triple colon](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-dblcolon.html) to expose a package's *hidden functions*:

```
rstatix:::pairwise_two_sample_test
```

output:

```
function (data, formula, method = "t.test", ref.group = NULL, 
    detailed = FALSE, ...) 
{
## ...
    res <- compare_pairs(data, formula, comparisons, method, 
        detailed = detailed, ...) %>% adjust_pvalue(method = p.adjust.method) %>% 
        add_significance() %>% p_round(digits = 3)
## ...
}
```

^^^ that `add_significance` part sounds promising.

- inspect hidden function `add_significance` (again: use triple colon)

```
rstatix:::add_significance
```

**ta-daa!**

```
function (data, p.col = NULL, output.col = NULL,
          cutpoints = c(0, 1e-04, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 1),
          symbols = c("****", "***", "**", "*", "ns")) 
{
## ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the search process :)